# display each character of a string as an underscore with a space between each underscore ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a word guessing game which takes a string as an input. I have found it very difficult trying to display each character of the string as an underscore with spaces between them. For example the word "cookie" to be displayed as `_ _ _ _ _ _` each underscore representing each character of the string. 
I have tried using scan and tr but haven't been able to get it to work. I have the following code:

```
class Game
  attr_reader :word
  attr_accessor :guess_counts

  def initialize(word)
    @word = word
  end

  def guesses_available
    @guess_counts = @word.length
  end

  def display
     print @word.tr_s('a-z','_ ')
  end

end


# user interface

puts "Please enter a word to initialize the Guessing The Word game"
  secret_word = gets.chomp

  game = Game.new(secret_word)

puts "you have #{@guess_counts} attemps left"
game.display
```

Comment: something along the lines of `'cookie'.gsub(/[a-z]/,'_ ').strip`

Comment: @sagarpandya82, ...or possibly `'cookie'.gsub(/./,'_ ').rstrip`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yeah that's better for sure.

Comment: Use the method [String#*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-2A): `str = "cookie"; puts "_ " * (str.size-1) << '_' #_ _ _ _ _ _`.

Comment: yet another variation... `('_ '*'cookie'.size).chop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with `tr` but you need to use the inversion operator `^` to *not* flip the guesses that match. Here's the core function you need:

```
def underscored(word, guesses)
  word.tr('^' + guesses, '_').chars.join(' ')
end
```

For example:

```
underscored('transistor', 'aebr')
# => "_ r a _ _ _ _ _ _ r"
```

If you append each guessed letter to a string, like `guesses << guess` then it works quite neatly with `tr`. Remember a string is fundamentally an array of characters, so don't bother making an explicit array for such things.

Comment: hey would you mind taking a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42709031/unable-to-reach-method-inside-if-else-statement-ruby

Answer (score 4):

Since you do not care about the actual characters, but want to present every character as a `_`, I would do something like this:

```
Array.new("cookie".length, '_').join(' ')
#=> "_ _ _ _ _ _"
```

Or:

```
('_' * "cookie".length).split(//).join(' ')
#=> "_ _ _ _ _ _"
```

Replace `"cookie"` with your string variable...

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you will eventually want to store the user's guesses and display only the letters they've guessed. Try this:

```
guesses = [] #letters guessed go into this array
@word.chars.map { |c| guesses.include?(c) ? c : '_' }.join(' ')
```

If you're just trying to display underscores for each letter without any additional logic, you can do this:

```
@word.chars.map { |c| '_' }.join(' ')
```

If you want to act on a single letter guessed by the user, you can do this:

```
letter = 'a' #or whatever letter you get from the user
@word.chars.map { |c| letter == c ? '-' : '_' }.join(' ')
```

Here's a simple but fully functional hangman example based on the first code snippet. Basically all i'm doing is running the first snippet in a loop and getting user input each time, doing a little bit of logic to see if they guessed the right letter, and keeping track of how many tries are left.

```
@word = 'boop'

guesses = [] #letters guessed go into this array
tries = 5

while tries > 0
  guess = gets[0]
  if !@word.include? guess
    puts "wrong."
    tries -= 1
    next
  end
  guesses << guess
  display = @word.chars.map { |c| guesses.include?(c) ? c : '_' }.join(' ')

  puts display

  if !display.include? '_'
    puts 'you win!'
    break
  end

end
```

Comment: I want to start by showing the number of characters as underscores for example. cookie would be display as _ _ _ _ _ _  if the input matches one of the characters in the string, for example the letter "o" I want to display it as        _  o o _ _ _ if user guesses letter "i" to display it as  "_ o o _ i _ " and so on

Comment: so if the word is 'boop' and the user guesses 'o', it will display '_ - - \_' ? then if the user guesses 'p' after that, the next display will be '_ _ _ -' ?

Comment: `'cookie'.chars.map { |c| '_' }.join ' '`

Comment: @sagarpandya82 thank you! i was hoping there would be a specific method for making a string into an array, but i didn't look hard enough.

Comment: @eiko how would I go about displaying the character if the user enters it right? for example the word is cookie and user enters "o" I would like to display. _ o o _ _ _

Comment: @StevenAguilar once a letter has been guessed, do you want it to stay visible for future guesses? or should only the letter that has just been guessed be visible?

Comment: A slightly weirder way is to use `*` instead of `join`: `'cookie'.chars.map { |c| '_' } * ' ' `

Comment: @eiko yes only the letter that have been guesses correctly! for example if a user enters a letter that is not a character in the word I would display a message saying "This letter is not in the word" and I would decrease the number of attempts left. But if user guesses a character that is part of the word I want to display the feedback as _ o o _ _ _  if the user enter "o"

Comment: @eiko is this a method inside the class? or is logic outside the class?

Comment: @StevenAguilar i wrote the code as logic which will run outside of a class or method. you could save it in a .rb file and run it with `ruby myfile.rb` if you want. but you can wrap it in a method or a class however you like. i think at this point, your original question has been answered. so go on and continue with your project- if you get stuck again, you can always make a new question!

Comment: @eiko hey would you mind taking a quick look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42709031/unable-to-reach-method-inside-if-else-statement-ruby

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of @guess_counts I would think about initializing it and adding one to it after each count and only calling game.guesses_available when telling them how many intial guesses they have.