# unable to reach method inside if else statement ruby

Tags: ruby

I am currently working on building a word guessing game. There is a word and a user would guess a character in the word. If the character the user guesses is in fact in the word then feedback would be given back. For example the word is "cookie" and the user enters "o" then feedback would be

`_ o o _ _ _`

the number of attempts is equal to the length of the word in this case 6. If the user guesses a character that is not part of the word for example "z" a message would display error. However I am having problems accessing the if and else statements, they work only for the first input. here is my code:

```html
class Game
  attr_reader :word
  attr_accessor :guess_counts, :guesses, :user_input, :guess_array 

  def initialize(word)
    @word = word
    @guesses = ""
  end

  def tries
    @tries = @word.length
  end

  def guesses(user_input)
    @user_input = user_input
    @guesses << @user_input
  end

  def underscored
   return @word.tr('^' + @guesses, '_').chars.join(' ')
  end

 
  
end


# user interface

puts "Please enter a word to initialize the Guessing The Word game"
  secret_word = gets.chomp

  game = Game.new(secret_word)

puts "you have #{game.tries} attemps left"


guesses = []
tries = secret_word.length

while tries > 0 
  puts "Plese enter a letter you believe is in the secret word"
  letter = gets.chomp
    game.guesses(letter)
    
    guesses << letter 
    guess = guesses[0]
    
    
    if !secret_word.include? guess 
      puts "Letter not in word"
      tries -= 1 
      puts "you have #{tries} left "
      next
    elsif secret_word.include? guess
      p game.underscored
    else 
      puts "you lost"
    end
 end
```

[image]

as you see in this image when I input "o" it says letter not in word but if I start with the letter "o" it would display
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are always grabbing the first element in the array of `guesses` when you wrote:

```
guess = guesses[0]
```

So the expression `!secret_word.include? guess` is:

- always `true` when the first guess is correct, and then is
- always `false` when the first answer is incorrect

To fix this you probably want grab the last guess; ie.

```
guess = guesses.last 

# `.last` is convenience method for accessing last element of an array; like so
#
#     guess = guesses[-1]
```

or the current `letter` for your `if` statement: i.e.

```
if !secret_word.include? letter
  # [...]
elsif secret_word.include? letter
  # [...]
```